# Group by DATEPART and DATEDIFF in LINQ .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

This SQL query works fine:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7

select DATEPART(YEAR, e.LogDate) Year,
    DATEPART(MONTH, e.LogDate) Month,
    DATEPART(DAY, e.LogDate) Day,
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, e.LogDate) DayName,
    DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, e.LogDate) - (DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DD, -DAY(e.LogDate) + 1, e.LogDate)) - 1) AS WeekNumber,
    e.Client,
    e.Status,
    COUNT(*) TotalCount from EmployeeProcessLogs as e
where e.Client = 'COUPA' and e.LogDate >= CAST('2020-1-1' AS datetimeoffset) and e.LogDate <= CAST('2021-1-1' AS datetimeoffset)
group by 
    DATEPART(YEAR, e.LogDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, e.LogDate),
    DATEPART(DAY, e.LogDate),
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, e.LogDate),
    DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, e.LogDate) - (DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DD, -DAY(e.LogDate) + 1, e.LogDate)) - 1),
    e.Client,
    e.Status
```

which give a result of:
[image]
**How can I get the same result with LinQ?**
This is what I've come up so far but it is giving me an error:

```
            var query = from l in _db.EmployeeProcessLogs
                        where l.Client == client &&
                              l.LogDate >= fromDate &&
                              l.LogDate <= toDate
                        let year = l.LogDate.Year
                        let month = l.LogDate.Month
                        let day = l.LogDate.Day
                        let dayName = l.LogDate.ToString("dddd")
                        let weekNumber = _.GetWeekNumber(l.LogDate.DateTime)
                        let clientType = l.Client
                        let status = l.Status
                        group l by new
                        {
                            Year = year,
                            Month = month,
                            Day = day,
                            DayName = dayName,
                            WeekNumer = weekNumber,
                            Client = clientType,
                            Status = status
                        } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Info = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Count()
                        };

            var hh = query.ToList();
```

The error says:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<EmployeeProcessLog>
    .Where(e => e.Client == __client_0 && e.LogDate >= __fromDate_1 && e.LogDate <= __toDate_2)
    .GroupBy(
        source: e => new { 
            Year = e.LogDate.Year, 
            Month = e.LogDate.Month, 
            Day = e.LogDate.Day, 
            DayName = e.LogDate.ToString("dddd"), 
            WeekNumer = ____3.GetWeekNumber(e.LogDate.DateTime), 
            Client = e.Client, 
            Status = e.Status
         }, 
        keySelector: e => e)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

This is the code for `GetWeekNumber`

```
        public int GetWeekNumber(DateTime date)
        {
            var gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            var firstDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
            var weekOfYear = gc.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
            var firstWeekOfYear = gc.GetWeekOfYear(firstDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
            return weekOfYear - firstWeekOfYear + 1;
        }
```

Comment: EF Core can't translate a method you wrote in C# to SQL so you can't use `GetWeekNumber` - you must inline a method using `DBFunctions`.

Comment: It seems like there is no easy way to do this in LinQ. I might end up using Stored Proc instead.

Comment: It worked for me using the following code instead --> let weekNumber = GetWeekNumber(l.LogDate)    NOTE: I did an example in LinqPad

Comment: @Brad In LINQPad, were you actually connected to your database?